# User should only be able to check one checkbox (html helper MVC C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, html-helper

The following code generates check boxes for each discount available for a product. If there are three discounts available, three check boxes will be generated. How do I ensure the user is only able to select one of these checkboxes (I didn't want to use radio buttons because I want to the user to have the option on clicking none of them). I want the user to only select one so that the data is easier handle in the controller. Thanks in advance!

```
<br />
<div>
    <strong>Discounts:</strong>
        @foreach (var discount in Model.Product.Discounts)
        {
            <br/>
            @Html.CheckBox("Product.Discount", discount, true, new { Id = string.Format("{0}-{1}", Model.Product.CourseId, discount.DiscountId) })
            @discount.Description
            @discount.Percentage
        }
    <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: What about having a radiobutton for 'none'? This would be clear and also stay inside the GUI standards..

Comment: +1 use RadioButtons - checkboxes are specifically for multiple selection. Why defy convention?

Comment: Ohhh I didn't even think of that! You saved me a lot of work. Thankyou!!

Answer (score 0):

In html, to link radiobuttons/checkboxes, you have to give them the same `name`

so add a `name = "pdiscount"` (you can call it whatever you want).

```
@Html.CheckBox("Product.Discount", discount, true, 
    new { Id = string.Format("{0}-{1}", 
           Model.Product.CourseId, discount.DiscountId), 
           name = "pdiscount" })
```